# How to take a screenshot from an video playing through MPMediaPlayerController in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, mpmovieplayercontroller, image-capture

Can anybody help me in this? I want to get an screenshot from an video playing through MPMediaPlayerController. What i have tried so far is:-

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
NSURL *tempFilePathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"LMFao" ofType:@"mp4"]];
player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:tempFilePathURL];
[player setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
//Place it in subview, else it won’t work
player.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400);
[self.view addSubview:player.view];
}

-(IBAction)screenshot
{
CGRect rect = [player.view bounds];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[player.view.layer renderInContext:context];   
image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 150, 100, 100)];
[imgView setImage:image];
imgView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
[self.view addSubview:imgView];
}
```

And what i ve got now is this:-

[image: ScreenShot]

what is happening now is my player's button are getting captured in ScreenShot but my video's image is not been getting.I'm using this context method to capture my image because
i have an overlay on my video,using thumbnail method i cant capture video with overlay but i want to get video's image with overlay.

**EDIT:**
what i want is getting screenshot of both this video and drawing overlay as shown in this image
[image: Overlay on Video]

But what i m getting is by one method i got only video not overlay in my screenshot that method is thumbnail method,i was doing thumbnailing in that which is given by MPMoviePlayerController and by second method i m getting only overlay not an video in ma screenshot,that method is context method.i'm getting context of rect.Now i thought solution for this may be is k i combine both these images.So help me out by giving suggestion is merging images will work for me or not???

Please help.Thanks :)

Comment: No Not at all,i'm using MediaPlayer framework for video playing nothing else i ve used :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can merge two image from this way.Please have an look from the below code..

```
- (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage {
    MaskView=[[UIView alloc] init];
    UIImageView *image1=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
    UIImageView *image2=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
    MaskView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0,500,500);    
    image1.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,160, 160);  
    image2.frame=CGRectMake(60,54,40,40);
    image1.image=image;
    image2.image=maskImage;
    [MaskView addSubview:image1];
    [MaskView addSubview:image2];   

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(160,160));

    [MaskView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *finishedPic = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); 

    return finishedPic;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just have to call a single method on your mpmovieplayer object:

`- (UIImage *)thumbnailImageAtTime:(NSTimeInterval)playbackTime timeOption:(MPMovieTimeOption)option`

this method will return a UIImage object. what you have to do is just:

```
UIImage *thumbnail = [player thumbnailImageAtTime:1.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
```

for more details look at [MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Hope this helps

**EDIT:** In your method you can first hide player's control and than capture Image after that show controls again. you can achive this using `controlStyle` property of MPMoviePlayerController.

Not sure this is what you are looking for but it is what I understood. If you are looking for different let me know.

Comment: I'm using this context method to capture my image because i have an overlay on my video,using thumbnail method i cant capture video with overlay but i want to get video's image with overlay.

Comment: I updated my answer. Let me know if this is still not what you are looking for

Comment: hey dude what i want to do is setting an overlay on video and capture an image.when i capture image video player's button are showing in image but video's image is not showing as shown in above screenshot.

Comment: with your answer there is a problem i.e.my overlay is not showing up.

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```
  - (UIImage *)thumbnailImageAtTime:(NSTimeInterval)playbackTime timeOption:(MPMovieTimeOption)option
```

Get the thumbnailImage at the given time and scale that image.

Comment: i have already done it,but its useless because i have an overlay on my video,with this thumbnail we can only get video's image not an overlay's image.!!!