# Is there any way other than thumbnail method to take a screenshot of an video in Iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image-capture

Is there any way other than thumbnail method to take a screenshot of an video? If yes then please tell me if not then please tell me how to resize an thumbnail image with a same resolution? i have getting an issue while taking screenshot of video.i have used this:-

[How to take a screenshot from an video playing through MPMediaPlayerController in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582943/how-to-take-a-screenshot-from-an-video-playing-through-mpmediaplayercontroller-i)

After this i ve used merging of an image by which i'm getting this[image: Resolution problem]

here image quality is my big issue.

I want this

[image: Required Output]

I want only video and drawing shown in above screenshot with same resultion.
Please help Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a way other than thumbnail method by which i can get screenshot of a video.!!!

The way is this :-

```
- (UIImage *)imageFromVideoURL 
{
// result 
UIImage *image = nil;

// AVAssetImageGenerator
AVAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:appDelegate.videoURL options:nil];; 
AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;

// calc midpoint time of video
Float64 durationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds([asset duration]);
CMTime midpoint = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(durationSeconds/2.0, 600); 

// get the image from 
NSError *error = nil; 
CMTime actualTime;
CGImageRef halfWayImage = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:midpoint actualTime:&actualTime error:&error];

if (halfWayImage != NULL) 
{
    // cgimage to uiimage
    image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:halfWayImage];
    [dic setValue:image forKey:kImage];
    NSLog(@"Values of dictonary==>%@", dic);
    NSLog(@"Videos Are:%@",appDelegate.videoURLArray);
    CGImageRelease(halfWayImage);
}
return image;
}
```

But still my problem is same i m drawing on video i cant get video's screenshot with drawing overlay,so for that i ve to use merging of images.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code.

```
    moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
    containerView =[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40,130, 240,219)];
    [moviePlayer setContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath]];
    [[moviePlayer view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, containerView.frame.size.width, containerView.frame.size.height)];  // frame must match parent view
    [self.view addSubview:containerView];
    [containerView addSubview: [moviePlayer view]];
    [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the screen shot of your video player at point of time you want. 
    And it's a standard method the to get the thumbnail of player with the time option.

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
UIImage *thumbnail = [player thumbnailImageAtTime:60.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];


UIImageView *imagV=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:thumbnail];
[imagV setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y, 200.0, 200.0)];
```