# Split videos to frames/images

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a requirement to split a 5 sec video to images /frames from my iphone.

Is it possible using objective C.Any libraries available for this?

Help is highly appreciable.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

there are many ways by which you can get images from a video. Some of them are :-

```
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:url];

MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];

UIImage *thumbnail = [player thumbnailImageAtTime:1.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];

//Player autoplays audio on init
[player stop];
[player release];
```

You can also check these links:-

[Is there any way other than thumbnail method to take a screenshot of an video in Iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612634/is-there-any-way-other-than-thumbnail-method-to-take-a-screenshot-of-an-video-in)

[How to take a screenshot from an video playing through MPMediaPlayerController in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582943/how-to-take-a-screenshot-from-an-video-playing-through-mpmediaplayercontroller-i)

It may help you :)

Thanks :)